# How do I visualize weight of conv_layer at the tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, visualization, tensorboard

I try to visualize weight of conv_layer at image format.

Below is my code for that.

```
def get_scope_variable(scope_name, var, shape=None):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name) as scope:
        try:
            v = tf.get_variable(var, shape)
        except ValueError:
            scope.reuse_variables()
            v = tf.get_variable(var)

    return v

# Add convolution layer
def conv_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="conv"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
        act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)

    tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)

    return tf.nn.max_pool(act, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")

def mnist_model(learning_rate, use_two_conv, use_two_fc, hparam):
  tf.reset_default_graph()
  sess = tf.Session()

  # Setup placeholders, and reshape the data
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x")
  x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
  tf.summary.image('input', x_image, 3)
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="labels")

  if use_two_conv:
    with tf.variable_scope('conv', reuse=True):
        conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 32, "conv1")

    conv_out = conv_layer(conv1, 32, 64, "conv2")
  else:
    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 64, "conv")
    conv_out = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")
```

And try to get weight variable named 'W'

```
  W_conv1 = get_scope_variable('conv', 'W')
```

But this trial give me error message.

> ValueError: Variable conv/W does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?

Please help me. I am stuck almost 1days.

Full code link of tensorboard example : https://github.com/mamcgrath/TensorBoard-TF-Dev-Summit-Tutorial/blob/master/mnist.py#L31

Comment: The code under `with tf.name_scope(name):` in `conv_layer` is not indented, is it a copy-paste problem or is your code like that ? In the second case you need to indent it. In get_scope_variable, why don't you use directly `with with tf.variable_scope(scope_name, reuse=True) as scope:` ? Is use_two_conv true or false in your usage ? If false then the variable you're looking for does not exist.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It must be intended.

Comment: Also, use_two_conv is true in my usage.

Comment: Then just use `W_conv1 = get_scope_variable('conv1', 'W')` instead of `W_conv1 = get_scope_variable('conv', 'W')`

Comment: It still gives me an error(ValueError: Variable conv1/W does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?). Jesus, helps me.

Comment: try reuse=None in VarScope (or even reuse=True). You can also replace tf.Variable() with tf.get_variable() in conv_layer, maybe that would work...

Comment: Why do you need get_scope_variable? I don't understand how is this related to tensorboard; does your normal training work?

Comment: It is just for ValueError. I failed to run this well anyway.